# Why the header "Accept: application/xml" does not work in Spring Boot after moving to Java 11?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, java-11

I want to move my Spring-Boot project from JDK 8 to 11.

**Controller :**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{model}/columns", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<DataModel> getColumnsModel(@PathVariable String model) {
        LOGGER.info("getColumnsModel : model[{}]", model);
        DataModel dataModel = modelService.getColumns(model);
        return Optional.ofNullable(dataModel).map(result -> new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK)).orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT));
    }
```

My JSON curl (OK in JDK 8 and JDK 11):

```
curl -s --header "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8084/noraui/api/hello/columns > target/actual_hello_columns.json
```

My XML curl (OK in JDK 8 but **not OK in JDK 11**):

```
curl -s --header "Accept: application/xml" http://localhost:8084/noraui/api/hello/columns > target/actual_hello_columns.xml
```

In JDK 11, the result is coming empty.

How to resolve this (I need use my code on JDK8 and JDK11)?

**EDIT:**

I have this error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]
```

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? Did you update Spring Boot as well?

Comment: Also, check the jackson version support for JDK 11.

Comment: I use springboot 2.1.6.RELEASE + JDK11 + maven-compiler-plugin source 1.8 and target 1.8

Comment: JDK11 doesn't have JAXB classes anymore. So without an explicit dependency on JAXB you cannot use XML on JDK11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the higher version of Jackson for XML support.

Add this dependency in `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

`spring-boot 2.1.6.RELEASE` call `jackson-dataformat-xml 2.9.9` only, if you up to `2.10.1`, it solves the issue.